# why/where the error "Permission denied for <http://ad.yieldmanager.com> to call method Location.toString"

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug

**EDIT:** I've added clarifications in response to a comment; where it's possible and meaningful, those added carifications are in *italic font style.*

*I've posted this question on Firefox groups as well as here on SO.*

There are at least 25 related questions on SO, a few representative questions being:

- [Flash bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902501/permission-denied-to-call-method-location-tostring)

  [cross-domain issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30540/what-does-this-javascript-error-mean-permission-denied-to-call-method-to-locatio)

  [just a mystery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656070/javascript-error-permission-denied-for-http-www-mydomain-com-to-call-method-l)

  [FF XPCOM problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127693/firefox-xpcom-component-permission-denied-to-call-method-unnamedclass)

There are ~15 accepted answers, none of which seem to apply here. Because there are so many questions and accepted answers, I am assuming that my question addresses an issue that developers have often tripped over.

*I have written a straight-up web page that, in my view, is completely normal and usual. I have nothing unusual on the page, nothing that I -- and probably you and all web developers -- haven't been using for the past ten years at least.*

I'm viewing the page I've developed with *Firefox 3.6.16 with Firebug 1.6.2.*

With varying periodicity, but typically every 30 to 60 minutes for 65% of the incidents, an error message shows up in the *Firebug* console:

```
Permission denied for <http://ad.yieldmanager.com> to call method Location.toString
```

Most of these message point at yieldmanager, but I see complaints about doubleclick and interclick as well. FB gives me no properties about the error messages.

View->Source of the page shows nothing about yieldmanager or any other offender.

There are calls to AdSense, but removing that code entirely changes nothing wrt the error messages.

There are about 3000 line of plain, vanilla-type JavaScript on the page but nothing at all exotic that I can see.

I have not explicitly or (I believe) implicitly included any framework code: no JScript, xjs, MooTools, not anything.

**Question:** How can I find out who is calling Location.toString( ); and how can I get rid of that guy?

Comment: Is this for your page or a general question?

Have you tried turning your extensions off?

Have you tried looking in Firebug's XHR viewer?

A question like this needs more context. What page? Can you link to the code? What extensions? And for those who don't happen to know common Firefox lingo: What's FF? (It's Fx, there's no such thing as FF) What's FB? (You meant Firebug, but we're not all psychic). This isn't Bugzilla, it's SO. Also, this could well be a Superuser question... although it's implied you're having this trouble with a page you wrote, it's not stated anywhere.

Comment: All good questions, thanks for taking the time to ask them in such detail. I'll edit my original ques.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may not be the case with you at all, however be aware that firebug will display error messages in your console if you open-up another window and browse to a site that has these calls. In short, these errors may not be related to your page at all.

Comment: Bingo! Yes, that's exactly what's going on. Thanks for the insightful answer!

Comment: you know, you might want to post your 100%-correct (not to say 'psychic') answer to the other 25 or so versions of the question on SO. Many others, I'm sure, are knocking themselves out looking high and low for this exact answer.

Comment: @Pete thanks, I'll try and do that :) by the way, this is my first ever accepted answer on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 1):

Per my comment, try disabling extensions (safe mode) and check Firebug's XHR tab if you haven't already.