# Replace url from youtube to embed code - Error: Permission denied to access property 'toString'

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

I have this code and this error in FireBug:

> Error: Permission denied to access property 'toString'

How can i fix this error?

HTML:

```
<div class="yturl">http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UNMLEZrukRU</div>
```

JS:

```
$("div.yturl").each(function(){
    var regex = /(\?v=|\&v=|\/\d\/|\/embed\/|\/v\/|\.be\/)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)/;
    var youtubeurl = $(this).text();
    var regexyoutubeurl = youtubeurl.match(regex);
    if (regexyoutubeurl) 
    {
         $(this).html("<iframe width=\"390\" height=\"315\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+regexyoutubeurl[2]+"\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>");
    }
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/9e48p/

Comment: Which versions of Firefox and Firebug are you using?

Comment: When I open the demo file in Chrome, the JS console in Chrome shows an error message as well: "Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://jsfiddle.net/9e48p/ from frame with URL http://www.youtube.com/embed/UNMLEZrukRU. Domains, protocols and ports must match."

Comment: And the same error has been reported for Vimeo users embedding Vimeo into iFrames: http://vimeo.com/forums/topic:28447

Comment: There are some other questions on SO dealing with the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30540, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/902501, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649102.

Comment: I'm facing this same issue when embedding facebook video in a webpage.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The error can either be fixed by Adobe's Flash Player team, or by the Google engineers - you should just ignore it for now. It's connected to Flash Player security settings and the SWF file embedded into the Youtube page. The problem has been [reported in the past by IBM](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21370430), and there is a [Mozilla Bugzilla entry](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=434522) as well.

When I deactivate Flash Player in Firefox 16.0.2, the error message disappears. Check comment #37: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=434522#c37

> For what it's worth, I'm seeing this bug happen when *any* flash file,
>   even ones that have NO actionscript calls (ExternalInterface, etc) in
>   them at all, is loaded into an iframe on a page where the page domain
>   and the iframe domain are different.  This means that the iframe
>   problem is caused when there is in fact a cross-domain situation in
>   place.  However, it's not totally clear if there's really actually
>   attempting to be a cross-domain call that *should* be prevented and
>   error'd out.
>
> Because it's nothing that the flash SWF itself is trying to call to do
>   "Location.toString", and it's nothing about the javascript on the page
>   doing it, the only choice is that there's something about the flash
>   plugin itself (9.0.124 is what I'm testing with) that's trying to make
>   that call up to the parent/top window to do Location.toString().

While the bug is marked as resolved, the test case attached https://bug434522.bugzilla.mozilla.org/attachment.cgi?id=321956 produces the same error message in the latest Firefox version (both in the Firebug console, or the Firefox Error Console window).

**Update:**
The bug has been filed with Adobe as well in the old bug database: [FP-561  "Location.toString" uncaught (security) exception caused by improper Flash plugin behavior](http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-561) (you need an account to see the bug details). The last comment there when the bug was closed:

> Tested with the latest Flash Player 10.3.181.34 on Firefox 4 and 5, no
>   such exception was thrown. So the bug may have been fixed, right? If
>   you still meet this issue, please file a bug in our new bug system
>   https://bugbase.adobe.com/ and put a link in the new bug to this
>   original JIRA report. We are happy to follow up your report in the new
>   bug system.

Comment: That would explain why there is no line number displayed for the JavaScript error, if the Flash Player is causing the problem.

Comment: The dates in bugzilla is really confusing. Its reported in 2008 and last modified in 2009. The bug's status is resolved and there is no comment under this bug for some time now.

Comment: The BugZilla ticket has been reopened under two new tickets: [#385676](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=385676) and [#1015700](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1015700) Anyone looking at the old ticket link will see it's closed / "fixed" but scroll down into the comments to get more info about it.

Answer (score 48):

Don't ignore this error just because its not related directly to your code.

It seems to occur when your embed is initialy hidden.

Just add `?html5=1` to your embed url. IE8 will still take flash version. or load your video with the Youtube api.

Comment: Outstanding. Wtf was all the Adobe engineers and Reported by IBM BS posted in the "accepted" answer above?

Comment: Maybe because the above is not a catch-all fix, and the accepted answer is showing that this is a bug originating from somewhere that you can't control? It's not BS when it's 100% relevant to the ticket that there's accepted bug reports filed and recognized by these people as something that's their fault.

Comment: +1 for improving my programming philosopy ("Don't ignore this error just because its not related directly to your code.")

Comment: This didn't resolve my issue. I still get the same error even after adding it

Answer (score 2):

Something is likely wrong with your Iframe url constructor. The error is being thrown in a youtube script that loads in the Iframe. The same error gets thrown with a harcoded html Iframe that isn't dynamically added with your script

```
<iframe width="390" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/UNMLEZrukRU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

HTML version only demo  http://jsfiddle.net/Lgt5f/

Double check the url isn't missing a parameter , otherwise I would check youtube support resources

Answer (score 1):

That issue can be caused by an extension that isn't working properly.

Start Firefox in Troubleshoot Firefox issues using Safe Mode to check if one of the extensions or if hardware acceleration is causing the problem (switch to the DEFAULT theme: Firefox/Tools > Add-ons > Appearance/Themes).

Answer (score -1):

Ignore that error, it's not related to your code. Just a browser bug.

Comment: Er, no, it is not just a browser bug.