# Most Javascript scripts don't work with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have developed a site with bootstrap framework version 2.0  (I can't upgrade version b/c at the beginning I made the terrible mistake to change the bootstrap.css file, nevermind)

By the way, all bootstrap javascripts are ok! The are working great, But when I'm trying to insert a script from http://www.dynamicdrive.com Nothing working, or script is not working correct.

I thought at the beginning that maybe the script has problem, So I try to insert the same script on a blank html page  without bootstrap libraries. Result: It's working perfectly.

Why is that happening? Am I forgetting anything to add on html code? How can I made these scripts work in my .html and .php files?

I tried many scripts from this site and only 1 or 2 worked.

A not working script for example is: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/dropinbox.htm

Of course I'm using html 5. Is this a problem?

Comment: I woul dstay far away from that dropinbox, it is annoying

Comment: I suspect that it's a problem with jQuery versions. That site is telling you to include jQuery 1.5.2 whereas Bootstrap will be using an up to date version of jQuery.

Comment: This is what your browser console is for.

Comment: @Shmiddty , I wrote my web console problem on an post below, please check that!

Answer (score 0):

Often, one error in a loaded javascript file will stop any other scripts on the page from working. Probably the new scripts have some sort of error in them. Check your browser's error console for anything red.

Once you've found the error message, google it.

You can catch syntax errors in the bud using a tool like http://jshint.com.

Finally, read up on [Javascript Debugging](http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/javascript_debugging_for_beginners/).

Comment: The only problem via  web console is a syntax error :  [19:07:36.963] SyntaxError: syntax error @ http://www.site.com/js/bootstrap-transition.js:1
[19:07:39.399] Error: Permission denied to access property 'toString'
[19:07:39.520] Error: Permission denied to access property 'toString'

Comment: Well, there's your problem. A quick google search of that error message brings us to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13100611/replace-url-from-youtube-to-embed-code-error-permission-denied-to-access-prop which may help. But I'm with @Iota: without the actual code to look at, all we can do is teach you [the fundamentals of debugging](http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/javascript_debugging_for_beginners/).

Answer (score 0):

First, please post the relevant JS in your question, rather than a link. Otherwise it will be difficult for us to help you : )

Second, use a code quality tool like [jsHint](http://www.jshint.com/) to check the javascript you are adding (as well as using your browser's console). Try slowly adding in sections of the script until something breaks.