# Can we fix Youtube denied 'toString' issue right now in 2013?

Tags: jquery, youtube, console

I using Firefox + Firebug and try to stop error msg...

`Error: Permission denied to access property 'toString'`

and in Chrome say..

`Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://jsfiddle.net/PEaUD/ from frame with URL http://www.youtube.com/embed/zTFBJgnNgU4?rel=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1&controls=0. Domains, protocols and ports must match.`

I just using jQuery something like ...

```
$("body").html('<iframe width="500" height="500" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/zTFBJgnNgU4?rel=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1&controls=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
```

**Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/PEaUD/

What's a problem ?

We cant fix it because ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/13101119/622813 ?

PS : I asking because in Firefox when I got this error , i can't play youtube videos, can't type/copy/pass (by keyboard) anyting in url bar when I clicked play-btn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you load your video using the youtube player api you won't get that specific error

https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, i think too. But I will do it so simple. If this is only way to stop error msg. so i have to use API :(

Comment: I think using the API is a good thing, it gives you a lot more control and power, you can make custom controls, do things once the video stops/starts, and really customize the users experiences, I would suggest using the API over the standard embed where possible

Comment: + i have to do with Vimeo also :P