# Circumvent Flash player bug while binding youtube events

Tags: javascript, firefox, youtube-api

I am using the following [Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988476/listening-for-youtube-event-in-javascript-or-jquery/7988536#7988536) to bind the `onStateChange` event of a Youtube Player contained in an iframe. As in the question I got the code from generating the youtube players through javascript is not an option for me.

I am experiencing this [Bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13100611/replace-url-from-youtube-to-embed-code-error-permission-denied-to-access-prop) in firefox.

```
Error: Permission denied to access property 'toString'
```

As described in the question I can't fix this since adobe or google have to do it apparently.

My Problem is that the callback function I am binding to the `onStateChange` event is not called. My code works perfectly in Safari but not in Firefox.

I suppose that this bug prevents me from setting the callback function correctly. Has anyone already written a workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on that specific bug that you're seeing in Firefox.

You should know that there are alternative approaches to dynamically inserting a YouTube iframe Player on a page in response to clicking on a placeholder element, though.

I've got a few examples of using static image thumbnails (with mouse-over "play" icons) that turn into auto-playing `<iframe>` players when clicked. You can see a live example in "My YouTube Videos" tab in the submission widget at the bottom of http://ytdirectlite.appspot.com/static-min/submit.html, and see the source code at

https://code.google.com/p/youtube-direct-lite/source/browse/static/css/index.css#150
https://code.google.com/p/youtube-direct-lite/source/browse/static/js/ytdl/panels/existing.js
https://code.google.com/p/youtube-direct-lite/source/browse/static/js/ytdl/player.js