# strange script error with firefox alone

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, youtube-javascript-api

If you open this [site](http://www.olympusmons.com/radio/) in chrome, it loads and runs ok but I tried loading it in firefox 19.0.2 and I keep getting a Script error asking me if I want to continue or stop.  After doing some searching around I found the about:config setting, but that doesn't help.  I installed firebug and I see an error about "Permission denied to access property 'toString'" but I have no clue as to what it wants or needs.  And the weird part is that if you go to another page in the same site like this [one](http://www.olympusmons.com/reggae) it works just fine. I'm clueless as to what it can be, so any help is much appreciated.

Not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13100611/replace-url-from-youtube-to-embed-code-error-permission-denied-to-access-prop), since it happens on one page but not the other and they both run the same exact code.  just that one loads a bit more data than the other.  More than anything I'm wondering if its the amount of facebook likes on one page?

Comment: Please look at the following link for more details
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13100611/replace-url-from-youtube-to-embed-code-error-permission-denied-to-access-prop

Comment: sorry but thats not exactly the same issue, since on one page it wont work and the other it will..and it uses the same exact code for playing the video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try to hit play button, you will get a JavaScript error in console in both Chrome and Firefox "TypeError: player is undefined". I tried it and the same error appeared in both console logs. It is and error in the page itself.

Answer (score 0):

I opened it in my firefox browser and it works fine. So it may be there is an add-on which did this error. Try to disable your installed add-ons from (firefox --> add-ons) and reload the page again. If it loads fine then you can enable your add-ons one by one to check which one causes this problem.

Comment: did you try hitting the play button at the top? i just disabled all my addons (2) yesscript and firebug and nothing.