# Error: Permission denied to access property 'toString' video is not playing in android

Tags: php, android, video

I am facing the issue of video not playing in android device. I checked the video functionality in firefox and getting the error "Error: Permission denied to access property 'toString'"
I searched a lot and found that we need to add the crossdomain.xml file to the rood of your domain. I tried this but still didnt worked.

Any help to resolve this will be really appreciable.

Comment: What kind of video is this? How do you embed it? Where is the `.toString()` method called? A *crossdomain.xml* is actually used to access Flash content over multiple domains.

Comment: Found this when searching for the error message: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13100611/911182

Comment: @insertusernamehere: I have used the following code for this.          <iframe src="http://content.streamhoster.com/player/ewcuniversity/0.%20New%20Uploads%20Waiting%20Posting/EWC%20HISTORY%20.mp4?autoPlay=1" width="854" height="480" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" webkitAllowFullScreen allowFullScreen></iframe>