# Facebook Embedded Video: Wrong protocol and out-dated flash player

Tags: facebook, flash, https, safari, embedded-video

I think I'm running into a couple issues. I am trying to embed a Facebook video using [their instructions here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player).

Worked fine in Chrome. When I tried in Safari the placeholder image would load fine, but when trying to play the video it kept spinning and I got series of these errors in my console:

```
Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.facebook.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://localhost:4000".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match.
```

Obviously I'm not running `https` on my localhost here, and I am developing for a site that is also `http`.

I then tried in Firefox and got a warning saying something to the effect of "this video can't play on your out-dated version of Adobe Flash player." When I installed the new version of Adobe Flash, it plays in both Safari and Firefox. However, I still get the "protocol" console errors in Safari, and I get the following console errors in Firefox:

```
- This site makes use of a SHA-1 Certificate; it's recommended you use certificates with signature algorithms that use hash functions stronger than SHA-1.
- Error: Permission denied to access property 'toString'
```

A couple questions:

1. How can I get rid of the console errors?
2. What can be done to either inform Safari users of an out-of-date Flash player or not use Flash? (I noticed it works on an iPhone which doesn't have Flash. Is there a way to tell Facebook to use another video format?)

Answer (score 0):

1. Warnings

For the Error: Permission denied to access property 'toString' warning, you can just ignore it, there is nothing you can do it to. Please read this answer with more details about it:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13101119/2389083

For the SHA-1 Certificate warning, it's a Firefox warning, please take a look at their blog post where they talk about it:
https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2014/09/23/phasing-out-certificates-with-sha-1-based-signature-algorithms/

2. Outdated Flash player

Each time you open a web that uses Adobe Flash player and the plugin detects your version is outdated, you should be prompted with a dialog to update your Flash version. I don't think you need to worry about that.