# extract String and alert as integer

Tags: string, extract

can anyone help me on that?

From the following string inside span with the classname "first" i want to extract the amount of price2.

So the jquery script needs to extract the "1 000.00" and devide that by 2 and give out that number (500) by an alert.

```html
<span class="first"><span class="second">Order</span>Price1: 1 100.00 USD Price2: 1 000.00 Price3: 1 200.00</span>
```

Is that possible? I only can extract the whole string but not the small part by leaving the rest untouched.

Thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Get the text first, then extract the number with `/Price2: ([\d. ]+)/` regex, then remove all spaces with `.replace(/\s+/g,'')` and then divide it by 2.

```js
var e = $('span[class="first"]');
var m = e.text().match(/Price2: ([\d. ]+)/);
if (m) {
  var res = Number(m[1].replace(/\s+/g,''))/2;
  alert(res);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="first"><span class="second">Order</span>Price1: 1 100.00 USD Price2: 1 000.00 Price3: 1 200.00</span>
```

**Details**:

- `/Price2: ([\d. ]+)/` matches `Price2:`  and matches and *captures into Group 1* one or more digits, spaces and dots. We only need Group 1, so we check if there is a match with `if (m)` and then access Group 1 with `m[1]`
- The string number with space cannot be converted to number type, we need to remove all whitesapces, and `\s+` matches  1+ whitespaces.
- The `Number()` is redundant, I just keep it for the code to be verbose and self-explanatory, `/2` would cast the result of `m[1].replace(/\s+/g,'')` to a number automatically.

Comment: I really have to thank you ... there seams to be a problem with another library or maybe with firefox. Here ist the error: Error: Permission denied to access property "toString"      Is there maybe a pure javascript version? Or a workaround?

Comment: I have just ran the snippet in FF 47.0 and got the `500` alert. I have just googled http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13100611/replace-url-from-youtube-to-embed-code-error-permission-denied-to-access-prop, please check.